# Compare String in Drools

Tags: java, drools

I have to compare String in Drools.

I tried:

```
rule "R52"
agenda-group "update rules"
salience -52
when
    $flgDetCnbFinOld == 'S'
then
    ...
```

*flgDetCnbFinOld* is passed from Java and the error I get is:

> Caused by: com.hp.drools.KieBuildException: Errors:   Message: {id=1,
>   level=ERROR, path=rules/doc-rules.drl, line=863, column=0, text="[ERR
>   102] Line 863:22 mismatched input '==' in rule "R52""}   Message:
>   {id=2, level=ERROR, path=rules/doc-rules.drl, line=0, column=0,
>   text="Parser returned a null Package"}

What is the correct way to compare String in Drools?

Comment: you have two errors: the second is "Parser returned a null Package 2". Are you sure your drl is correct?

Comment: Did you ever look at the Drools manual? The definition of the syntax for rules? Left hand side? Patterns? Constraints? Binding variables? - In Drools, you can compare string values using "==", that's correct, but all the rest is not correct.